# Is there a map equivalent operation in CNTK?

Tags: cntk

I have an input variable X with a dynamic axis. I want to do something like this: map(function,X) where function will return also a tensor

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your function, you might just be able to write

```
Y = function(X)
```

Unless `function()` does something specific regarding sequences, 
this will automatically apply the expression to every element of the sequence,
and return a sequence of the same length.